# Neo4j return subgraph based on certain id

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My database stores family relationships.

What I am trying to do is to return the whole family tree of a person with a certain ID.

I have tried the following query:

```
MATCH (p:Person {id:'1887'})-[r*1..3]-(k:Person)
RETURN distinct(p), r, k
```

but I didn't get the result that I wanted.

To make it more clear, I would like to get all the relationships that a person with specified ID has, along with the relationships of all the other nodes that he is connected to.

To explain further, here is an example:

Boris is a parent of Mike and Anna. Apart of seeing Boris' relationship to them, I also want to see Mike and Anna's further relationships with their subgraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should try returning the complete path, like this:

```
MATCH path = (p:Person {id:'1887'})-[r*1..3]-(k:Person)
RETURN path
```

This query will store each the path between a person with `id = 1887` and another person with depth 1 to 3 and return it. Or if you are interested only in the nodes you can extract it with the [nodes()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-nodes) function:

```
MATCH path = (p:Person {id:'1887'})-[r*1..3]-(k:Person)
RETURN nodes(path)
```

Comment: I have another question regarding this:

I would need the data returned in the following order `p.firstname, TYPE(r), k.firstname` . For example: 
`Eric - PARENT_OF - Mia;  
Eric - PARENT_OF - Peter;
 Mia - SIBLING_OF - Peter;
 Mia - SPOUSE_OF - Mark`

Comment: @Porjaz you are trying to get a response with a dynamic number of columns. I believe this is not possible with Cypher. Also, you are asking a new question in the comments. I suggest you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/360570) this answer if it solved your original question to informs other users that this problem is solved and to help future viewers of this question.